# NodeJS Async Waterfall inside function always return null

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I call a function and inside the function there is an async waterfall

```
validateInput = function(req) {

  async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      if(req.body.username == null)
         return 'Username cannot be null';
      callback(null);
    }, function (callback){
      if(req.body.name == null)
         return 'Name cannot be null';
      callback(null);
    }
 ],function(err){});
}
```

Here is how I call the function

```
validateInput(req);
```

The problem is it always returns null.
How to call the function so it doesn't return null?

Comment: what do you mean by returns null? are you sure that req body has correct data?

Comment: Req.body has correct data for sure. But when I call `validateInput(req).length`, it gives me error `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`, which means the function doesn't return anything. It seems the function skip anything inside async waterfall

Comment: `validateInput(req)` return value will be always *undefined*, since the function is asynchronous. See my answer, to understand how to use an `async.waterfall()`...

Answer (score 1):

You should **always** call `callback()`, even when errors occur...
Try something like this:

```
validateInput = function(req) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
      if (req.body.username == null)
         return callback(new Error('Username cannot be null'));
      callback(null, 'username is ok');
    },
    function (resultFromPreviousCallback, callback) {
      if (req.body.name == null)
         return callback(new Error('Name cannot be null'));
      callback(null, 'name is ok');
    }
 ],
 function(err, resultFromLastCallback) {
   // if err is null, all async.waterfall functions
   // did pass, otherwise, you get the first error
   // you can safely ignore `resultFromLastCallback`...
 });
 // you correctly do not return anything, here,
 // since this function is asynchronous...
}
```

For your use case, you can probably ignore all the results from the functions, since you're only interested in validating some fields...
But this explanation is more general, and illustrates the usage of `async.waterfall`...

Comment: In your second function you are not accepting result1 mate.

Comment: @NitishAgarwal: thanks, I did update it... OP will not probably use `results`,  in this case, but you are right...

Comment: It's nice to know that if you don't need the result from the **previous** callback, you *should* use `series`, which aggregates the result from all functions and pass it to the last handler.

Comment: You're right. Though in this case I think OP don't need the result from the **previous**, nor from **any** callback: she only needs the **err** indication...

Answer (score 0):

```
validateInput = function(req) {

  async.waterfall([
    function(callback){
      if(req.body.username == null)
         return 'Username cannot be null';
      callback(null);
    }, function (callback){
      if(req.body.name == null)
         return 'Name cannot be null';
      callback(null);   //**Return whatever you want to return here**
    }
 ],function(err){});
}
```

Basically while using this callback you can use something like
callback(null,X)

Another case which is arising here will totally depend upon your use case means do you want this function call to be asynchrnous or not.
I can be of more help if you provide me the code snippet from where you are calling this function.